# I cannot get the value of my Entry in Tkinter | Python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

So I am making this GUI app with tkinter in which we can signup and login and save our data. I am having problem with getting the value from the Entry widget in my signup part.

```
from tkinter import *

##### CONSTANTS ############
m = Tk()
m.title("Info storage")
m.geometry("500x500")
############################

def signup():
    sw = Toplevel()
    sw.title("Sign Up")


    signup_head = Label(sw, text="Sign Up over here!", font=font1, padx=180).grid(row=0, column=0)

    username_text = Label(sw, text="Username", font=font2, pady=40).grid(row=1, column=0)
    username = Entry(sw, width=40)
    password_text = Label(sw, text="Password", font=font2, pady=10).grid(row=3, column=0)
    password = Entry(sw, width=40)
    re_password_text = Label(sw, text="Re-type your password", font=font2, pady=10).grid(row=5, column=0)
    re_password = Entry(sw, width=40)
    useless = Label(sw, text=" ", pady=50).grid(row=7, column=0)


    username.grid(row=2, column=0)
    password.grid(row=4, column=0)
    re_password.grid(row=6, column=0)
    

    def signup_work():
        p = password.get()
        my_p = Label(sw, text=p).pack()


    go_btn = Button(sw, text="GO", width=20, command=signup_work).grid(row=8, column=0)



title = Label(m, text="Login or Signup to start storing your info!", width=50, height=3, font=font1).grid(row=0, column=0)
signup_button = Button(m, text="Sign Up", command=signup).grid(row=1, column=0)

m.mainloop()
```

This is the error that I am getting

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "F:\software\Python 3.9.7\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__                                           
return self.func(*args)                                                                                               
File "D:\Programming\Python\Tkinter\info-storage\main.py", line 38, in signup_work                                        
my_p = Label(sw, text=p).pack()                                                                                       
File "F:\software\Python 3.9.7\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2396, in pack_configure                                     
self.tk.call(                                                                                                       
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!toplevel which already has slaves 
managed by grid
```

I didn't even put a windows geometry function on my second window but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that you are packing/gridding the widgets in the same line that their object is initialized, and then you save them in a variable.
Like so -:

```
my_p = Label(sw, text=p).pack()
```

This would not give the desired results, as what is actually being saved in variable for example here `my_p` is of `None` type, as it is the return value of the function pack and not the `Label` object itself.
The fix to this is to pack the Label in a separate line -:

```
my_p = Label(sw, text=p)
my_p.pack()
```

Secondly, `pack` and `grid` are two tkinter geometry managers that cannot be used on the same parent's widgets.
For example in your code the problem is that to the same parent `sw`, the Label `my_p` is being packed and many other widgets are being gridded.
And as explained tkinter cannot handle the packing and gridding of widgets of the same parent, thus it throws the error -:

> _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!toplevel which already has slaves  managed by grid

By changing the geometry manager for the label `my_p` to grid instead like so -:

```
my_p = Label(sw, text=p)
my_p.grid(row = some_row, column = some_column)
```

The problem can be fixed.